# Inline editing in react

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

Hi So I have localStorage, I displayed it in list, there is two input elements price and quantity.
I want to allow them to be edited without redirecting to another form.
I want to edit price and quantity in list (inline-editing).
This is my code now:

```
const ProductsPreview = (props) => {
  const [deleted, setDelete] = useState(false);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    let locProducts = localStorage;
    setProducts(locProducts);
  });

  function setNewQuantity(event) {
    setProducts({ ...products, quantity: event.target.value });
  }

  function setNewPrice(event) {
    setProducts({ ...products, price: event.target.value });
  }

  function saveInlineEdits(event) {
    localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(products));
  }

  function deleteHandler(key) {
    localStorage.removeItem(key);
    setDelete(!deleted);
    alert('Product with id: ' + key + ' deleted!');
  }
  return (
    <ProductList
      saveInlineEdits={saveInlineEdits}
      setNewQuantity={setNewQuantity}
      setNewPrice={setNewPrice}
      products={products}
      setProducts={setProducts}
      deleteHandler={deleteHandler}
    ></ProductList>
  );
};

const ProductList = (props) => {
  return (
    <div style={style.container}>
      <TableHeader></TableHeader>
      {Object.entries(props.products).map(([key, valueJSON]) => {
        const value = JSON.parse(valueJSON);
        return (
          <div
            id={key}
            key={key}
            style={
              value.quantity <= 0 ? style.highlight : style.gridItemsContainer
            }
          >
            <p>{value.name}</p>
            <p>{value.ean}</p>
            <p>{value.type}</p>
            <p>{value.weight}</p>
            <p>{value.color}</p>
            <input defaultValue={value.price} onChange={props.setNewPrice} />
            <input
              defaultValue={value.quantity}
              onChange={props.setNewQuantity}
            />
            <input
              defaultChecked={value.active}
              onChange={value.active}
              type="checkbox"
            />
            <Link style={style.viewButton} to={'/products/' + key}>
              VIEW
            </Link>
            <Link style={style.editButton} to={'/products/' + key + '/edit'}>
              EDIT
            </Link>
            <button
              style={style.deleteButton}
              onClick={() => props.deleteHandler(key)}
            >
              DELETE
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <Link style={style.addProductButton} to="/products/create">
        Add new product
      </Link>
      <button
        style={{ position: 'absolute', marginTop: '50px' }}
        onClick={() => props.saveInlineEdits}
      >
        Save Inline Edits
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image]

Edited code as Red Baron offered.
How to save localStorage without a key, set it equal to products state?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to allow editing then change this:

`<input value={value.price} />`

to be: `<input defaultValue={value.price} />`

and then remember to set state with it so you can capture the new input

`<input defaultValue={value.price} onChange={(e) => setNewInput(e.target.value)}/>`

then after you've got the new input, hit `save` somewhere and re-save it to `localStorage`

Comment: Thanks, I will try it, and write you back

Comment: how setNewInput should look like? How to set localStorage there?

Comment: you need to set state for all the inputs you want to update. then I suggest you write a function that "re-saves" it to localstorage and gets all the values from state. does that make sense? or do you need an example?

Comment: example would be perfect

Comment: I think what you should do is this. instead of doing this: `{Object.entries(localStorage).map(([key, valueJSON]) => {` you should put all the localStorage into your local component state and then map over the state instead. that way you can edit the state as you go and then you put it back in localstorge whenever you like

Comment: https://pastebin.com/hGFvHv50
Made it to state, plz look at my setNewInput function when i change input value i get error TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined. How should that method look, I think i need to pass key somehow.

Comment: sorry I am planning to look at this. just not got round to it yet